# Calculate Big Theta Notation Bubble Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, bubble-sort

I'm trying to calculate the theta notation for bubble sort but I'm getting stuck. Given this procedure (pseudocode):

```
procedure BUBBLE_SORT(A,n) {
    array A(1 to n)
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= n-1; j++) {
            if(A[j] > A[j+1] {
                //swap(A(j), A(j+1))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to get the worst case running time with sigma notation to be:

(n^2 - n) / 2

For the best case running time, I followed my book and did this:

Given p(n) = (n^2 - n) / 2, we claim that p(n) = Θ(n^2). To prove this we show that for some constants c1, c2 and n0:

C1n^2 <= (n^2 / 2) + (n / 2) <= C2n^2

Dividing both sides by n^2, we get:

C1 <= (1 / 2) + (1 / 2n) <= C2

This is where I got lost. In the book, the author picked out some numbers, plugged them in and said "Therefore it follows that p(n) = Θ(n^2)"

How do I know what numbers to plug in? Can I just plug in any numbers? And if those numbers do fit the inequality, does that mean I can immediately say that the algorithm is Θ(n^2)?

Thank you!

Comment: woops you're right! thanks for pointing it out. editing now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that this is about asymptotic behavior.

We can think about it as playing a game: Your goal is to prove that a certain bound holds. The game goes like this: First, you get to chose the constants `C1` and `C2`. Then I get to chose an arbitrary `n`. If I can do this in a way that it violates the inequality, you lose (the bound does not hold). If there is no way I can do this, even though you are no longer allowed to change the `C1` and `C2` that you picked, you win (the bound is correct).

Let's look at the equation in question now:

C1 <= (1 / 2) + (1 / 2n) <= C2

Since `n` is an integer (in the end, it represents the number of elements in your array), there is a definite smallest value: `n = 1`. Let's substitute that in:

(1 / 2) + (1 / 2) = 1

Alright, now that's a start. Let's see what happens as I make `n` bigger... Note that the `n` only appears in the denominator. So I cannot mess up your bound by making it arbitrary big. The worst case for you is actually for *small* values of `n`. With bigger values of `n` the second part of the product gets smaller and eventually disappears. For the limit `n->inf` we get:

lim n->inf (1 / 2) + (1 / 2n)

(1 / 2) + lim n->inf (1 / 2n) = (1 / 2) + 0 = 1 / 2

So what that tells us is, whichever value of `n` I choose, the resulting value will *always* be in the range 1/2 to 1 (since the equation is linear in `n` these two samples are enough to show that; with more complex equations, establishing the bounds usually requires a little more work).

With this knowledge, can you pick `C1` and `C2` in a way that I can never win the game?

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation :) Do we always take n = 1 when computing for Θ? And is showing that there exists bounds C1 and C2 enough to say that it is Θ(n^2)? If say I can find an exception, would that make it not Θ(n^2)?

Comment: Q1: You need to figure out the asymptotic behavior of the function, so usually you are only interested in large `n`s. In the end, you don't have to literally chose the constants, you just have to show that they exist. Q2: If, for every `C1` and `C2` that you chose, I always can find an n that violates the inequality, the bound is false. Of course if you do a crappy job at choosing them I can always come up with an n. But since we are dealing with an existence proof here, it is enough to show that it is possible to choose C1 and C2 in a way that I can never win, no matter which n I pick.

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

We are interested in finding `C1` and `C2` such that the following holds for every `n >= 1`:

`C1 <= (1 / 2) + (1 / 2n) <= C2`

A good choice for `C1 = 1/2` (but any strictly positive value smaller than that is also valid, e.g. `C1 = 0.1`).

A good choice for `C2 = 1` (but any value larger than that is also valid). The value `C2 = 1` is fine because the expression `1 / 2 + 1 / 2n` decreases as `n` becomes larger, thus its maximum value is for `n = 1`.

---

One final note: it was shown above that there are some constants `C1` and `C2` for which the inequalities always hold when `n >= 1`. If it were more convenient, we could have focused on values of `n` starting from another constant value (instead of `1`, e.g. `n >= 10000`). What is important is that there are some constants `C1` and `C2` so that both inequalities hold when `n` is large enough.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach that I follow is to check standard complexity values first. like 
`2^(2^n) > n! > 4^n > 2^n > n^2 > nlogn > log(n!) > n > sqrt(n) > (logn)^2 > logn > loglogn > 1`

This way just plugin `n^2` Now if it satisfies then consider values less than that. This way you can get the tight bound. If it doesn';t satisfy go for higher values. This helps in lots of cases.

Comment: @Katrina.: i actually mentioned the plausible values to plugin...that's it.